# JavaScript: Accessing Variables from Other Files and Changing their Properties

Tags: javascript, variables

So I am making a hacking type game coded with HTML and JavaScript, and I made a Store.html file for my store to purchase upgrades for your hacking system. I have several variables that I want to view and change from a different file than the one that I originally have it inside of.

**Variable 1**

```
var tutorialDone = false
```

**Variable 2**

```
var jobBoolean
```

**Variable 3**

```
var bitCoins = 30
var currentBit = bitCoins
```

I want this to be false because when the tutorial mission is finished, then I want to change the jobBoolean variable to "true" because when the tutorial mission is completed, then I want a new list of missions/jobs to show up on thee screen. The first mission is a seperate page. At the end of the mission when it is completed, then "tutorialDone" I want to be equal to "true", so that when I am back at the homepage, I can change the jobBoolean to true. Because the "tutorialDone" variable is dependent on the "jobBoolean" variable. When "tutorialDone" equals "true" so does "jobBoolean". I don't know how to make "tutorialDone" change along with the "jobBoolean".

I have for the third variable, there is two. That is because they are similar. I have a function inside the "Store.html" document that when an item is purchased, it grabs a variable which in this case is "currentBit". "currentBit" is equal to "bitCoins" because I thought that if I made a new variable, "currentBit", then set it equal to "bitCoins", it would connect with "bitCoins" from a seperate file. This was my only "solution" I could think of, but it doesn't work.

Also, as a bonus answer for you guys, how can I make an "if" statement in JavaScript, and then have it check if the variable I give it is equal to something, and if it is, run some code. Because whenever I try it, the function the if statement is in, it will run through the if part of the statement no matter if the statement is true or false.

Sorry if this question doesn't make much sense. This is just the first big problem I have encountered with JavaScript, that I couldn't fix myself.

Comment: I don't have any idea what you're trying to do.

Comment: You can use the *strict equals operator* to compare two values: `a === b` returns `true` if the value of `a` is equal to the value of `b`. I recommend to read a [**JavaScript tutorial**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide). Regarding the variables, I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to do, but you can't create an implicit connection to between two variables. You have to change both explicitly.

Comment: Fine to write it in short: Can any of you tell me a way to change a variable from a different file/page? I just want to be able to change a Boolean variable to true or false, and a number variable to a different number, from a different file. Example: When I reach the end of the tutorial mission, the variable "jobBoolean" will be changed to "true". This function needs to change the variable "jobBoolean" to true without being in the same file.

Comment: Are you talking about different HTML pages? Or just different JS files loaded into the same page? If the it's the former, there is no way to do this, because only the code of the currently loaded page "exists". If it's the latter, all script files share the same global scope, so if you have global variables, all you have to do is access them.